# Delete single row above button BUT don't allow it to delete if

Tags: vba, conditional-statements, row, delete-row

I am using form control buttons to add and delete the rows above the button. There are several sections per worksheet, hence the find function.

Adding the row has no issue.  The question is about deleting rows... to a limit.

The Code:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Dim Found  As Range
    Set Found = Columns("B").EntireRow.Find(what:="          Remove Row ", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Rows(Found.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

The problem is that I don't want the end user to delete rows containing headings.  I'd like to add something that will stop the sub if the row above the *Found.Row* contains the text "Travel Expenditures".

It's a "if" I suspect, but I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

(Novice User)

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. A couple comments:

1. Do you need all the whitespace around `"Remove Row"`?
2. `Columns("B").EntireRow` is the entire sheet - I'm assuming you wanted just `Columns("B")`.

I revised your code based on these 2 issues.

```
Sub ConditionalDelete()
    Dim Found As Range, Found2 As Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Set Found = Columns("B").Find(what:="*Remove Row*", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Set Found2 = Rows(Found.Row - 1).Find(what:="Travel Expenditures")
        If Found2 Is Nothing Then
            Rows(Found.Row - 1).Delete
        End If
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could `Intersect` rows and column with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to limit scanned ranges

and here's a code with `Application.Match` method, which I believe is faster than Range.Find(), but is case insensitive:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    Dim iRow As Variant

    iRow = Application.Match("          Remove Row ", Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("B")), 0)
    If Not IsError(iRow) Then
        If IsError(Application.Match("Travel Expenditures", Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Rows(iRow - 1).EntireRow), 0)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Rows(iRow - 1).Delete
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Ben's worked but I'll try yours, too.